Artifactory conan repository returns 404 instead of 401/403
I have Artifactory 7.84.14 CPP CE instance on our server hosting conan repository. When user token expires (or user is not authenticated), Artifactory returns error code 404 instead of 401/403. Result of this is, that conan returns "Package not found" instead of "Please authorize".
> conan install --remote someremote --requires=somepackage/version@some/repo
> ERROR: Package 'somepackage/version@some/repo' not resolved: Unable to find 'somepackage/version@some/repo' in remotes.

In the artifactory-request.log file is line with 404 code.
anonymous|GET|/api/conan/package/path|404|-1|0|5|Conan/2.7.1 (Windows 11; Python 3.12.3; AMD64)

Now. I found mansion about hideUnauthorizedResources config options (here and here). Problem is, this configuration is already there. Here is config descriptor xml (from AF GUI):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<config xmlns="http://artifactory.jfrog.org/xsd/3.3.5" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="https://releases.jfrog.io/artifactory/static-release-virtual/xsd/artifactory/artifactory-v3_3_5.xsd">
    ...
    <security>
        <hideUnauthorizedResources>false</hideUnauthorizedResources>
        <passwordSettings>
            <expirationPolicy>
    ...

and here is artifactory.repository.config.latest.json:
{
    "localRepoConfigs":
    [
        {
            "type": "local",
            "key": "somerepo",
            "packageType": "conan",
            "baseConfig":
            {
                "modelVersion": 2,
                "description": "",
                "notes": "",
                "repoLayoutRef": "conan-default",
                "includesPattern": "**/*",
                "excludesPattern": ""
            },
            "repoTypeConfig":
            {
                "archiveBrowsingEnabled": false,
                "blackedOut": false,
                "propertySetRefs":
                [],
                "checksumPolicyType": "client-checksums",
                "priorityResolution": false,
                "maxUniqueSnapshots": 0,
                "handleReleases": true,
                "handleSnapshots": true,
                "snapshotVersionBehavior": "unique"
            },
            "packageTypeConfig":
            {
                "forceConanAuthentication": "false"
            },
            "securityConfig":
            {
                "hideUnauthorizedResources": false,
                "signedUrlTtl": 90
            },
            "repoType": "LOCAL"
        }
    ]
    ...
}

So, my question is, what I'm missing? Why I'm getting 404 instead of 401/403?

Did you try setting forceConanAuthentication to true and restart services just to see if it is working right?  false is the right setting, but setting it to true might give you something besides 404.

Wow! That is a solution! Thank you!!!!! Maybe, do regular answer to mark as solution here :)

Try setting forceConanAuthentication to true and restart services just to see if it is working right? false is the right setting, but setting it to true might give you something besides 404 and allow it to work properly.
